# How to fix invalid syntax error in definition of inner functions in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

The below code throws an invalid syntax error in line 12:

> 'def run():'  is invalid syntax.

I don't see any mistake I could possible make there.

```
def removelastodd(numbers):
        odd = []
        flag = False
        for num in numbers:
            if num % 2 == 1:
              flag = True
              odd.append(num)
        if flag:
          return numbers.pop(odd.index(odd[-1])
                          
                          
    def run():
      numbers = [1, 7, 2, 34, 8, 7, 2, 5, 14, 22]
      removelastodd(numbers)
    
    run()
```

Comment: Your indentation seems weird. Can you please double check whether this is the same as in your script file?

Comment: There is a closing parenthesis missing on the line before.

Comment: check your syntax,your `run()` function seem inside the other function

Comment: Note that if the last odd number occurs multiple times, you will pop the wrong occurence of that number.

Comment: Why not just use `return numbers.pop()` since the default is the last index of the list?  This avoids the issue when the number occurs multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method :

```
def removelastodd(numbers):
    nums=[]
    flag=False
    for i in numbers[::-1]:
        if i%2==0:
            nums.append(i)
        elif i%2==1:
            if flag:
                nums.append(i)
            flag=True
    return nums[::-1]
                                               
def run():
    numbers = [1, 7, 2, 34, 8, 7, 2, 5, 14, 22]
    print(removelastodd(numbers))
     
run()
```

Output:

```
[1, 7, 2, 34, 8, 7, 2, 14, 22]
```